# My decorator change my function output, how to avoid this? Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, decorator

I need decorator which will remowe whitespaces from start and end of the strings(they're given like function parameter) and i have it:

```
def decorator(function):
    def someFunc(*strings):
        function(*strings)
        newstr = []
        for x in strings:
            newstr.append(str(x).strip())
        return newstr
    return someFunc
```

and let's imagine I'll use a function:

```
@decorator
def myFun(*args):
    str = ""
    for i in args:
        str = str + i
    return str
print(myFun("  aaaa  ", "   bbbb   ", "   ccccc   "))
```

output:

```
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccccc']
```

but i need:

```
'aaaa,bbbb,ccccc'
```

So i want to make it universal for any function output.
And at the time a want it to output right for this func:

```
@decorator
def func1(*strings):
    return strings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a list, not a string. You could join this list on the comma character to get the output you wanted:

```
return ','.join(newstr)
```

Comment: thanks, but if i'll need to ouput also a list or tuple in another func:
@decorator
def func1(*strings):
    return strings